# Hibernate: How to solve circle

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-onetomany

I am fighting the following problem and I want like to implement a clean solution.

Imagine this Entity-Diagramm:

[image: Circle]

A Book has Pages and for every book a user cann add Notes. For every Note the user can specify many Pages to which the Note references to.

When I ceate a new structure of this and try to save it I get the following exception:

```
TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : NoteToBokPage.page -> page",
```

So Hibernate tells me to save the Page first, before I can save the NoteToBookPage. That would mean I cannot cascade the save for all items.
Would it be the best way then to set all entities to CASCADE.ALL instead of the NoteToBookPage and then do the save for the NoteToBookPage speratly manually? Is that a good approach?

My Problem is, that my structure acutally is bigger. Book is not the root. There are two layers above and my plan was to offer just one update methode for the whole tree by triggering a update on the root element with cascading everything. It seems to be ugly, when saving everything with cascade, instead of one leaf and doing that manually afterwards.
Is there a possibility to tell Hibernate that it has to do the save on the Page first, before saving the NoteToBookPage? I hoped it works when I put the PageList-Attriubte in the Book-Class above the NoteList-Attribute, but it did not.

Any ideas how to handle this the sexy way?

Thank you

Comment: I am not sure I can follow, but adding your actual code (or a simplified example to reproduce the problem) helps. In theory JPA is pretty simple: Either you work with a single entity so all entities you are working with elsewhere should be managed or you use cascades if you want to save a whole graph at once.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem.

The problem occured when I created a dummy entity structure and tried to save that. I made the mistake, that the entity that was referenced by another entity was not the same Java Instance. I created a new instance with same the same values, but because I use the standard java object equals/hascode hibernate doesnt recognized it as equals.

When I create my dummy structure I have to make sure that all entities referenced are actually the same java object instance. Then hibernate is able to persist the whole structure at once.